# no tooltip shows for JLabel in JPanel in a column of a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have an application that displays the space taken up by files in a directory tree; it uses a JTable, each row is one level in the tree, and the rightmost column displays a line of JLabels showing the percentage of space occupied by files with each extension found. If the user changes the width of the app window, the last column changes to accommodate it, and the JLabels change to reflect their percentage of the new column width. That's all working.

I recently decided to include a tooltip on each label, so that the user can look up the exact percentage if desired. However, I can't get the tooltip to show up.

I use a custom renderer for the rightmost column. It creates 50 JLabels when constructed, then modifies the dimensions on the ones it needs, when rendering, to avoid having to create the objects repeatedly. I tried just putting JLabels with tooltips in a JPanel; that works with no problem but, of course, isn't usable in my application. I also tried overriding `getTooltipText()` in the panel containing the JLabels, but couldn't get `getComponentAt()` to work.

I wondered if someone could point out where I've gone wrong on the tooltips.

SizeBlockTester.java

```
package sizeblocktester.filedata;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

/**
 * Test frame for an unexpected behavior of a Swing UI; a label inside a panel 
 * used as a value for a column does not display its tooltip. The good stuff is
 * in SizeBlockTesterPercentageRenderer.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SizeBlockTester extends JFrame
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SizeBlockTester tester = new SizeBlockTester();
    tester.go();
  }
  
  public void go()
  {
    createUI();
    setVisible(true);
  }
  
  private void createUI()
  {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    SizeBlockTesterJTableModel model = new SizeBlockTesterJTableModel();
    SizeBlockTesterJTable table = new SizeBlockTesterJTable(model);
    table.setDefaultRenderer(SizeBlockList.class, new SizeBlockTesterPercentageRenderer());
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_LAST_COLUMN);
    
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    
    pack();
  }
}
```

SizeBlock.java

```
package sizeblocktester.filedata;

/**
 * A block of something to display; for this test, size and percentage are set to the same thing.
 */
public class SizeBlock
{
  private String  label;
  public  String  getLabel() { return label; }
  
  private long  size;
  public  long  getSize() { return size; }
  
  private int percentage;
  public void setPercentage(int value)  { percentage = value; }
  public int  getPercentage()           { return percentage; }
  
  public SizeBlock(String givenLabel, long givenSize)
  {
    label = givenLabel;
    size  = givenSize;
    percentage = (int)givenSize;
  }
  
  public String toString() { return label; }
  
}
```

SizeBlockList.javav

```
package sizeblocktester.filedata;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * A list of SizeBlock, put in its own class so we can assign a default renderer to it.
 * @author ralph
 *
 */
public class SizeBlockList
{
  public SizeBlockList (ArrayList<SizeBlock> givenList) { list = givenList; }

  private ArrayList<SizeBlock> list = new ArrayList<SizeBlock>();
  public ArrayList<SizeBlock>   getList()                               { return list; }
  public void                   setList(ArrayList<SizeBlock> givenList) { list = givenList; }
}
```

SizeBlockTesterJTable.java

```
package sizeblocktester.filedata;

import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

/**
 * This extension of JTable lays out the table such that
 * resizing a column widens or narrows the column to its 
 * right, and resizing the window just widens or narrows
 * the last column.  
 * @author rcook
 *
 */
public class SizeBlockTesterJTable extends JTable
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  
  public SizeBlockTesterJTable(SizeBlockTesterJTableModel model)
  { super(model);
  }
  
  public SizeBlockTesterJTableModel getDirTableModel() 
  { return (SizeBlockTesterJTableModel)getModel(); 
  }
  
  /**
   * set the widths of the columns so that the last column
   * gets any extra or narrows to accommodate any surfeit
   * needed.
   */
  public void doLayout()
  {
    TableColumnModel model = getColumnModel();
    int tableWidth = getWidth();
    int usedWidth = 0;
    // add up the widths of all columns except the last
    int columnCount = model.getColumnCount(); 
    for (int i=0; i<columnCount - 1; i++)
    {
      int width = model.getColumn(i).getWidth();
      usedWidth += width;
    }
    // set the width of the last column to the remaining space
    int lastWidth = tableWidth - usedWidth;
    model.getColumn(columnCount-1).setWidth(lastWidth);
  }
}
```

SizeBlockTesterTJableModel.java

```
package sizeblocktester.filedata;

import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SizeBlockTesterJTableModel extends AbstractTableModel 
{
  SizeBlockTesterTableRow[] rowList = new SizeBlockTesterTableRow[] 
      { 
          new SizeBlockTesterTableRow("dum", "dee", "Alice", 75, "WRabbit", 25)          , 
          new SizeBlockTesterTableRow("Laurel", "Hardy", "Kukla", 60, "Fran", 40)
      };

  @Override
  public int getRowCount()     { return rowList.length;  }
  public int getColumnCount()  { return 3;  }
  
  public Object getValueAt    (int row, int col)                        { return getColumnValue(rowList[row], col);     }
  public Object getColumnValue(SizeBlockTesterTableRow row, int col)    { return row.getColumnValue(col);               }
  public Class<?>  getColumnClass(int colNumber)
  {
    Class<?> c = null;
    // columns 0 and 1 are strings, 2 is the sizeBlockList.
    if (colNumber <= 1) { c = String.class; }
                   else { c = SizeBlockList.class; }
    return c;
  }
}
```

SizeBlockTesterPercentageRenderer.java

```
package sizeblocktester.filedata;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

//import rcutil.color.NamedColor;


/**
 * a Size Block is an object with a string name, long size, and an int
 * percentage. This renderer takes a list of such size blocks and creates a
 * component to display each size block within a JTable cell such that each
 * block's percentage is reflected as the relative width of that block in the
 * cell. <B>Furthermore, the string label on the cell is used as an key into a
 * hashmap that tracks the color being used for that index; the same color is
 * used on each call to the renderer.
 *
 * @author rcook
 * 
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SizeBlockTesterPercentageRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
    implements TableCellRenderer
{
  boolean blueBackground = true;    // toggles so we can alternate colors for backgrounds

  private static final int MINIMUM_LABEL_WIDTH = 10;
  private static final String REST_OF_TYPES_STRING = "---";

  // the container panel is the one we'll return; In it we'll put one JLabel for each
  // size block being represented on that row.
  private JPanel containerPanel = new JPanel();
  
  // this array of JLabels is put in the container panel; we set the width
  // and the background color based on its label and its percentage,
  // respectively.
  // it is sized so that we never need more JLabels than this for one row
  // of the display (since we're currently doing percentages, 50 seems safe).
  private static final int MAX_LABELS = 50;
  private JLabel[] sizeBlockLabels = new JLabel[MAX_LABELS];
  private Dimension[] sizeBlockDimensions = new Dimension[MAX_LABELS];
  private JLabel REST_OF_TYPES_LABEL = null;

  public SizeBlockTesterPercentageRenderer()
  {
    containerPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(containerPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
    
    sizeBlockLabels = new JLabel[MAX_LABELS];
    sizeBlockDimensions = new Dimension[MAX_LABELS];
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LABELS; i++)
    {
      JLabel l = new JLabel();
      l.setOpaque(true);
      sizeBlockLabels[i] = l;
      sizeBlockDimensions[i] = new Dimension(10, 10);
      containerPanel.add(sizeBlockLabels[i]);
    }
    REST_OF_TYPES_LABEL = new JLabel();
    REST_OF_TYPES_LABEL.setBackground(Color.gray);
  }

  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent
      (JTable  table,       Object  givenList, 
       boolean isSelected,  boolean hasFocus,
       int     row,         int     col)
  {
    SizeBlockList sizeBlockList = (SizeBlockList) givenList;

    // set the height and width of the container panel to that of the cell
    // (row height, column width)
    int rowHeight = table.getRowHeight(row);
    int columnWidth = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(col).getWidth();

    // remainingWidth keeps getting set to the width we have not yet used up
    // on the display. done is set to true when we're done displaying things.
    int remainingWidth = columnWidth;
    boolean done = false;

    int i = 0;
    for (SizeBlock sizeBlock : sizeBlockList.getList())
    {
      // create a panel for each sizeBlock, setting the width according to
      // the percentage of space it uses. Since we're reusing JPanels, they're
      // already added to the containerPanel, so we don't need to do that here.
      String labelText = null;
      int newWidth = (columnWidth * sizeBlock.getPercentage()) / 100;
      if (newWidth < MINIMUM_LABEL_WIDTH)
      {
        labelText = REST_OF_TYPES_STRING;
        newWidth = remainingWidth;
        done = true;
      } 
      else
      {
        labelText = sizeBlock.getLabel();
      }
      remainingWidth -= newWidth;
      
      sizeBlockDimensions[i].setSize(newWidth, rowHeight);
      sizeBlockLabels[i].setPreferredSize(sizeBlockDimensions[i]);
      sizeBlockLabels[i].setMaximumSize(sizeBlockDimensions[i]);
      sizeBlockLabels[i].setBackground(blueBackground? Color.CYAN : Color.green); blueBackground = !blueBackground;
      sizeBlockLabels[i].setText(labelText);
      sizeBlockLabels[i].setToolTipText(String.format("%d%%", sizeBlock.getPercentage()));
      sizeBlockLabels[i].setVisible(true);
      i++;
      if (done)
      {
        break;
      }
    }
    
    for (int j = i; j < MAX_LABELS; j++)
    {
      sizeBlockLabels[j].setVisible(false);
    }
      
    containerPanel.doLayout();
    return containerPanel;
  }

  // The following methods override the defaults for performance reasons
  public void validate()  {  }
  public void revalidate()  {  }
  protected void firePropertyChange(String propertyName, Object oldValue, Object newValue)  {  }
  public void firePropertyChange(String propertyName, boolean oldValue, boolean newValue)  {  }
}
```

SizeBlockTesterTableRow.java

```
package sizeblocktester.filedata;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SizeBlockTesterTableRow
{
  String firstValue;
  String secondValue;
  SizeBlockList sizeBlockList;
  
  public SizeBlockTesterTableRow(String a, String b, String x, int c, String y, int d)
  {
    firstValue = a;
    secondValue = b;
    ArrayList<SizeBlock> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new SizeBlock(x, c));
    list.add(new SizeBlock(y, d));
    sizeBlockList = new SizeBlockList(list);
  }
  
  public Object getColumnValue(int col)
  {
    Object result = null;
    switch (col)
    {
    case 0: result = firstValue;    break;
    case 1: result = secondValue;   break;
    case 2: result = sizeBlockList; break;
    default: System.out.println("No value in row for col " + col);
    }
    return result;  
  }
  
}
```

I apologize for the amount of code, but on SO one is always admonished if there's no minimal working example, and I cut this down to the extent I could.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: *, but on SO one is always admonished if there's no minimal working example* - As I understand it your question is about displaying a tooltip on a JLabel that is added to a panel used as a renderer. For an [mre] all you need is a custom renderer that has two labels on a panel and you display the tooltip based on the label the cursor is over. All the logic about dynamically resizing the labels is irrelevant to the stated problem. Custom TableModel is irrelevant. First you get the simple solution to work, then you apply the solution to your app.

Comment: For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31238676/tooltip-position-for-cell-in-jtable/31238769#31238769)